# How to use the "About Me" without evolution

Tags: gnome, evolution

As the title suggests, I want to use the About Me section under System>Preferences without using evolution. (I don't have evolution installed on my computer as I handle email/calendering etc via google apps)

As it stands I get an error message unless evolution is installed which means I can't establish a profile properly on the Indicator Applet Session as it seems to pull from 'About Me'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately in order to use About Me (part of the gnome-control-center) the application needs to take advantage of `evolution-data-server`, which is the service that let's the rest of the desktop connect to mail/contacts/task, etc.

Ideally someone would write a program that would sync e-d-s to your Google App account (or whatever) in order to take advantage of this feature -- unfortunately nothing like this exists as far as I know.

References:

- [Bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=408158) for support in Mozilla Thunderbird
- [Bug report](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=431034) for support in OpenOffice.org
- [e-d-s Documentation](http://www.go-evolution.org/EDS_Architecture)